# Delete N number of rows from table considering date time as decimal(16,4)

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL table which is created by CFDB Plugin in a wordpress installation. As the size have grown up tremendously, I need to remove the older entries (Say, I need to keep only one year data). The data is saved with an index 'submit_time' which is of data type decimal(16,4). How would I achieve this using SQL query.

The structure is like https://pasteboard.co/In0JWMU.png

SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`;
CREATE TABLE`wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`(`
submit_time`decimal(16,4) NOT NULL,`
form_name`varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,`
field_name`varchar(127) DEFAULT NULL,`
field_value`longtext,`
field_order`int(11) DEFAULT NULL,`
file`longblob,
  KEY`submit_time_idx`(`submit_time`),
  KEY`form_name_idx`(`form_name`),
  KEY`field_name_idx`(`field_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: Can you provide your table structure please?

Comment: Why 'submit_time' is of type 'decimal' instead of timestamp? Can you show what sort of data this column contains? I'm asking because this is our target column here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by the following query using FROM_UNIXTIME.

```
DELETE FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(submit_time) < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
```